# can't using site.css ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am building a website using datatables jquery and css from https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html using visual studio.

The jquery working perfectly on my website. However, Now I can't use my custom css on my website. all the template and style basically following the jquery and css file provided from that source. Does anybody know why?

Comment: what is the hierarchy of all the css you are using? kindly share the code.

Comment: put ur script after all the css

Comment: I put my css style in site.css, and there is also datatables.css and datatables.min.css which are from the datatables jquery. 
what i want to use is style in site.css

Comment: what is mean by putting the script after all css?

Comment: The problem is the order in which your CSS files are loading. Make sure that your custom CSS files is loaded AFTER the others

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define your custom css after the datatable css by adding  tag of **datatable css** before **site.css** or if there are some style still missing that you might need to use **!important** attribute with those styles. That's it!

Comment: do you know some site talking about this? or can you show me how ?